# Pivot Table Number Ranges - Novice

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I am a complete novice to excel and having my first go with Pivot Tables.

I have sheets with lost of data mostly numeric, these sheets contain up to 80,000 rows and 25 columns.

I am using pivot tables to filter the data and have managed to get it going ok to give me the values I require.

However I would like to now add the ability to break down the filter ranges into numbers with between values.

For example I have one particular column with numbers ranging from -600 to +2450.

I would like to look at values between 35 and 180 for example without having to select multiple values in the filter and then tick every box i require.

Is this possible for a novice (I have no idea what or where VBA is having had a look around

IF it is possible would it then be possible to do the same for columns that contained a certain piece of text

Hope someone can help

Ian

Answer (score 0):

this is how i would do it.

let's say your "one particular column with numbers ranging from -600 to +2450" is column A.

You can set a new column with the formula IF(OR(A*>=35,A*<=180),1,0),
drag the formula to fill the rest of the cells in the new column,
filter the new column for 1 and it should display all the rows where the values are more than 35 and less than 180.

if it doesn't work with the pivot table, try select all the data in the pivot table, copy and paste the data as values to a new sheet.

you can try it for text as well. just if you are searching for "APPLES" in a column A, 
use IF(A*="APPLES",1,0) in a new column and filter out 1.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For ad-hoc analysis, you could right-click on the relevant field header and select *Value Filters* and *Between*. This will save ticking/unticking every number in the range.

You can also group your data field. If you e.g. have the following pivot table layout:

```
Header1    Header2    Data
A          AB         1234
           AC         2345
           AD         3456
B          BB         4567
```

you can select e.g. AB-AC and right-click and *Group...* the items. This will add another column with the grouped Header2 fields:

```
Header1    Header2_2  Header2    Data
A          Group1     AB         1234
                      AC         2345
           AD         AD         3456
B          BB         BB         4567
```